# PHP files fail to connect to MySQL Android Studio login/register app

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-connection, access-denied

I am creating an app that will allow users to login and register. The app appears to be running correctly however there issue with the connection between the app and the server. When I run the app and register a new user, the details I just enter do not enable me to login. I think the problem lies with the PHP files as it does not appear as though registered users are being added to the SQL database, however I cannot see how to fix it. When I open the file in Chrome I get the PHP error message:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'a9650904_John'@'10.1.1.27' (using password: YES) in /home/a9650904/public_html/Register.php on line 2

These are my PHP files

FetchUserData.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql7.000webhost.com","a9650904_John","a9650904_********","a9650904_User");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $county, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user["county"] = $county;
    $user["username"] = $username;
    $user["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Register.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql7.000webhost.com","a9650904_John","a9650904_********","a9650904_User");

    $name = $_POST["county"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (county, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $county, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here are links to the files
http://johngriffin.netau.net/FetchUserData.php and http://johngriffin.netau.net/Register.php

If anybody has any idea as to what I could do to fix this problem, your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Now that you have posted your credentials someone will steal all of your data.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Whatever is in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This error

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'a9650904_John'@'10.1.1.27' (using password: YES) in /home/a9650904/public_html/Register.php on line 2

signifies that your php file cannot connect to your database because of error in your database configuration access information.

Check that you have add correct information here

```
$con=mysqli_connect("", "", "", "")
```

Comment: I am fairly certain it is this line where the issue is coming from, I'm just unaware of how to correct it?

Comment: You can reset you username and password with new values and try to use it again.

Comment: Should I enter a9650904_ before all of the variables except the local host?

Comment: Hope you followed this pattern - mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); If yes, may be you contact the host admin.

Comment: Yes that is the pattern that I am following. I have tried multiple slight variations of this to no avail though.

Comment: Can you login to your database admin side and check all the values.

Comment: I changed a9650904_User to a9650904_John and PHP error is gone however the connection between the app and the database is still not working.

Comment: Do this first -  $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
  } If no error is print then we will proceed to the second problem.

Comment: I added that line to both of the php files but the issue persists.

Comment: I'm using android studio should the error message appear in logcat?

Comment: No, it should display in the php file. You can test your php code independent of your android app.

Comment: That error message doesn't appear. Instead I get a fatal error: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\jjohn_000\AppData\Local\Temp\~Untitled 1 on line 2 PHP Stack trace: PHP 1. {main}() C:\Users\jjohn_000\AppData\Local\Temp\~Untitled 1:0

Comment: Check if mysqli extension is enable in your server. You can see it by using this line of code - phpinfo();

Comment: I just downloaded PHP Designer 8 free trial and now it won't run the files at all as it says "No input file specified."

Comment: Disclaimer - I wrote this tutorial about android login with php - http://inducesmile.com/android/android-user-login-and-registration-with-retrofit-php-mysql-and-slim-framework/. See if it can work for you. If not we can move the discussion in chat section.